# Custom price value in minicard is wrong only on single product site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a function that changes the price of a product in my shopping cart.

Actually everything works. I can add the product to the shopping cart, complete the order and everywhere comes my custom_price.
When I add the product via the archive page, everything works fine (widget-cart and shopping-cart).

But if i add the product via the single-product-site, the price in the widget shopping cart is not correct. But the total is then correct again.

[Screenshot Archive Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrtkA.png)

[Screenshot Single Product Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq5yB.png)

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart', 'add_custom_price' );

 function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

  if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
                    $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id(); 
        }               

            $product_group = get_field( "produktegruppe", $product_id );
            $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $usergroup = get_field($product_group,'user_'. $current_user_id);
            $value1 = $usergroup['rabatt'];
            $value2 = $usergroup['zusatzrabatt'];

            $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->get_price() );
            if ( $value2 ) {
                $discPrice = ($orgPrice / 100 * (100-$value1)) / 100 * (100-$value2);
            }
            else {
                $discPrice = $orgPrice / 100 * (100-$value1);               
            }    
            $value['data']->set_price($discPrice);

    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?